# Problem with reverse copying an array to another array inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays

So my question is why is my fourth function not working as intended? It is supposed to take an array and turn it into a reversed copy of another array, I feel like the logic is sound but in the end it is just spitting back out junk data when I have it print. I'm a student and this is for a class, I have emailed the teacher but she just about never responds so I thought I would ask you guys. And before someone says duplicate, I know there are other things on how to reverse copy arrays but I want to know what about my logic is wrong. What is making this one not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void inputData(ifstream& y, int x[], int a);

void printData(ofstream& y, const int x[], int a);

void copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int a);

void revCopy(const int orig[], int rev[], int a);


int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arr1[size];
    int dup[size];
    int revdup[size];
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    inputData(infile, arr1, size);
    printData(outfile, arr1, size);
    copyArray(arr1, dup, size);
    revCopy(dup, revdup, size);
    printData(outfile, revdup, size);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void inputData(ifstream& y, int x[], int a)
{

        y.open("infile.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            y >> x[i];
        }
        y.close();

}

void printData(ofstream& y, const int x[], int a)
{
    y.open("outfile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        y << " " << x[i];
    }
    y.close();
}

void copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        dup[i] = orig[i];
        cout << dup[i] << endl;
    }

}

void revCopy(const int orig[], int rev[], int a)
{
    for (int i = a; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int n = 0;
        rev[n] = orig[i];
        cout << rev[n] << " " <<orig[i] << endl;
        n++;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have it using an input text file to make the first array then outputting an array then outputting the last array to a text file in order to check if it worked. The first 3 functions work just fine, but the last function is not giving me back what I thought it would and I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: note where you set n to 0.

Comment: thanks man i feel dumb as hell now lol
I need to get some sleep that was an incredibly dumb mistake.

Comment: Set n to 0 outside for loop otherwise it'll always be 0

Comment: alright so I did that, and it works but for some reason the first item in my array is now junk data but the rest is fine, any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: You start the for loop with `int i = a` but `a` isn't a valid array index. For zero-based indexing the valid range is [0..a-1].

Comment: Thank you man I appreciate it, that got it working, don't know why I didn't catch that.

Comment: If this wasn't for a class I'd tell you to use `std::reverse_copy(orig, orig + a, rev);` from the C++ standard library.

Comment: @stark Do you want to post an answer so Matt can accept it and you get  some rep?

Comment: @Blastfurnace how do I set it so that the question is answered and be done with it? kinda new to the site.

Comment: You can post your own answer and "accept" it. A brief diagnosis of the error and how you corrected it. You can include your fixed version of the function. Stack Overflow encourages self-answered questions if they might help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So as it would turn out, it was just a couple foolish mistakes due to being tired. In my revCopy method I put int n = 0 inside my for loop which made it reset every time (obviously) to zero. I also tried to start indexing my reversed copy of the array at [10]. This wouldn't work because the array only has 10 data points (0-9) in it so logically the last data point is [9] not ten. Once those two simple changes were made the program functions flawlessly. Thank you @Blastfurnace, @stark and @crack_iT for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void inputData(ifstream& y, int x[], int a);

void printData(ofstream& y, const int x[], int a);

void copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int a);

void revCopy(const int orig[], int rev[], int a);


int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arr1[size];
    int dup[size];
    int revDup[size];
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    inputData(infile, arr1, size);
    printData(outfile, arr1, size);
    copyArray(arr1, dup, size);
    revCopy(dup, revDup, size);
    printData(outfile, revDup, size);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void inputData(ifstream& y, int x[], int a)
{

    y.open("infile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        y >> x[i];
    }
    y.close();

}

void printData(ofstream& y, const int x[], int a)
{
    y.open("outfile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        y << " " << x[i];
    }
    y.close();
}

void copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        dup[i] = orig[i];
        cout << dup[i] << endl;
    }

}

void revCopy(const int orig[], int rev[], int a)
{   
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = (a-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        rev[n] = orig[i];
        cout << rev[n] << " " <<orig[i] << endl;
        n++;
    }

}
```